# How to add diffrent colour in Slider div

Tags: jquery, html, css

This is my site : http://daplonline.in/index9.php

I want to add different colour in CSS link

IIT-JEE(Adv) - 2014, JEE MAIN - 2014, AIPMT/Guj-CET - 2014, GSEB - 2014, CBSE - 2014

HTML code is here

```
<nav>
    <a class="pink"  href="#">IIT-JEE(Adv) - 2014</a>
    <a href="#">JEE MAIN - 2014</a>
    <a href="#">AIPMT/Guj-CET - 2014</a>
    <a href="#">GSEB - 2014</a>
    <a href="#">CBSE - 2014</a>
</nav>
```

CSS Code

```
.mi-slider nav {
    position: relative;
    top: 330px;
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    left: 30px
}

.no-js nav {
    display: none;
}

.mi-slider nav a {
    display: inline-block;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    padding: 40px 0px 10px 34px;
    position: relative;
    color: #888;
    outline: none;
    -webkit-transition: color 0.2s linear;
    transition: color 0.2s linear;
    background: #3498db;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3498db, #2980b9);
    font-family: Arial;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 4px 8px 6px 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.mi-slider nav a:hover,
.mi-slider nav a.mi-selected {
    color: #000;
    background: #3498db;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3498db, #2980b9);
    font-family: Arial;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 4px 8px 6px 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.mi-slider nav a.mi-selected:after,
.mi-slider nav a.mi-selected:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: -5px;
    border: solid transparent;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.mi-slider nav a.mi-selected:after {
    border-color: transparent;
    border-width: 20px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -20px;
}

.mi-slider nav a.mi-selected:before {
    border-color: transparent;
    border-width: 27px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -27px;

}

.mi-slider ul.li a pink 
{
    background:#FF3366; 
}
```

I added a class `.pink` but it's not working. I want to 5 colour link.

Comment: different color for each of the links or just a common particular color to each?

Comment: If you want to provide a live demo (awesome, please do!) don't just point us to your site because, once you've resolved the problem, the demo disappears. Use a site such as [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/) or many, *many*, others.

Comment: diffrent color for each link 

IIT-JEE(Adv) - 2014, 
JEE MAIN - 2014, 
AIPMT/Guj-CET - 2014, 
GSEB - 2014, 
CBSE - 2014

Comment: @user3705511 check my answer and the fiddle..

Comment: i know @Js Bin but there are not possible to always create demo do you have answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this if you want to give different color to your links

**HTML**

```
<a class="pink"  href="#">IIT-JEE(Adv) - 2014</a>
<a class="yellow" href="#">JEE MAIN - 2014</a>
<a class="green" href="#">AIPMT/Guj-CET - 2014</a>
<a class="red" href="#">GSEB - 2014</a>
<a class="blue" href="#">CBSE - 2014</a>
```

**CSS**

```
.pink{ background: pink;}
.yellow{ background: yellow;}
.green{ background: green;}
.red{ background: red;}
.blue{ background: orange;}
```

If you want to give same color to all your links give them a common class like this

**HTML**

```
<a class="CommonColor"  href="#">IIT-JEE(Adv) - 2014</a>
<a class="CommonColor" href="#">JEE MAIN - 2014</a>
<a class="CommonColor" href="#">AIPMT/Guj-CET - 2014</a>
<a class="CommonColor" href="#">GSEB - 2014</a>
<a class="CommonColor" href="#">CBSE - 2014</a>
```

**CSS**

```
.CommonColor{ background: grey;}
```

**Fiddle:** [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sid_m/2aLnE/1/)

Comment: did you checked the fiddle?

Answer (score 2):

first of all make it in ul li like this

```
<nav>
   <ul>

      <li  class="pink"> <a href="#">IIT-JEE(Adv) - 2014</a></li>
      <li  class="red"> <a href="#">JEE MAIN - 2014</a></li>
      <li class="yellow"> <a href="#">AIPMT/Guj-CET - 2014</a></li>
      <li class="gray"> <a href="#">GSEB - 2014</a></li>
      <li class="blue"> <a href="#">CBSE - 2014</a></li>
   </ul>
</nav>
```

here is css code

```
.mi-slider nav {
        position: relative;
        top: 330px;
        max-width: 1200px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        left: 30px
    }

    .no-js nav {
        display: none;
    }

    .mi-slider nav ul li {
        display: inline-block;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        letter-spacing: 5px;
        padding: 40px 0px 10px 34px;
        position: relative;
        color: #888;
        outline: none;
        -webkit-transition: color 0.2s linear;
        transition: color 0.2s linear;
         background: #3498db;
      background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
      background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
      background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
      background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
      background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3498db, #2980b9);
      font-family: Arial;
      color: #ffffff;
      font-size: 15px;
      padding: 4px 8px 6px 8px;
      text-decoration: none;
    }

        .mi-slider nav ul li.pink {
        background:#FF00FF;

        }
          .mi-slider nav ul li.red {
        background::#FF0000;

        }
     .mi-slider nav ul li a{
        display: inline-block;
        text-transform: uppercase;
      text-decoration: none;}

    .mi-slider nav ul li:hover,
    .mi-slider nav a.mi-selected {
        color: #000;
         background: #3498db;
      background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
      background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
      background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
      background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
      background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3498db, #2980b9);
      font-family: Arial;
      color: #ffffff;
      font-size: 15px;
      padding: 4px 8px 6px 8px;
      text-decoration: none;
    }

    .mi-slider nav a.mi-selected:after,
    .mi-slider nav a.mi-selected:before {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        top: -5px;
        border: solid transparent;
        height: 0;
        width: 0;
        position: absolute;
        pointer-events: none;
    }

    .mi-slider nav a.mi-selected:after {
        border-color: transparent;
        border-width: 20px;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -20px;
    }

    .mi-slider nav a.mi-selected:before {
        border-color: transparent;
        border-width: 27px;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -27px;

    }

    .mi-slider ul.li a pink 
    {
        background:#FF3366; 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

well looking at your css and html you have shown. there might be some problem with the css classes you added.

you have

```
.mi-slider ul.li a pink 
{
    background:#FF3366; 
}
```

but the link is under a nav and there is no li.

```
<a class="pink"  href="#">IIT-JEE(Adv) - 2014</a>
```

There were the problems.

make these changes

```
<nav>
 <li><a class="pink"  href="#">IIT-JEE(Adv) - 2014</a></li>
 <li><a class="red"  href="#">AIPMT - 2014</a></li>
 <li><a class="green"  href="#">xyz - 2014</a></li>
</nav>
```

and add css like this

```
nav li a.pink{ background: pink;};
nav li a.pink:hover{//hover styling}

nav li a.red{ background: red;};
nav li a.green{ background: green;};
```

Comment: An `<li>` element is only a valid child of a `<ul>` or `<ol>` (unless something new has happened in HTML 5 of which I'm unaware?) **edited** *and*, apparently, the `<menu>` element (reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li).